# soap4r  SOAP::FaultError

Tags: ruby, soap-client, soap4r

I am new to soap and I am having the problems with it already! I am using soap4r gem.

```
gem 'soap4r', :git => 'git://github.com/felipec/soap4r.git'
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
require 'soap/rpc/driver'
require 'soap/mapping/mapping.rb'
```

And I initialize the rpc driver as follows:

```
 def initialize
    @username = "username"
    @password = "password"
    endpoint = "https://someurl.php"
    namespace = "abc:somenamespace"
    @driver = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new(endpoint, namespace)
  end
```

When I visit the endpoint from the browser I am getting this error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
<faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for this service
</faultstring>
<detail xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Also, when I do this from irb:

```
client = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new("endpoint?wsdl").create_rpc_driver
```

I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: part: return cannot be resolved
    from /home/sadiksha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/wsdl/soap/methodDefCreator.rb:144:in `rpcdefinedtype'
    from /home/sadiksha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/wsdl/soap/methodDefCreator.rb:56:in `collect_rpcparameter'
.
.
.
```

But when I do this:

```
client = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(endpoint).createDriver
```

and list methods by

```
client.methods(false)
```

and I have one method getName. When I try to access that method by client.getName({:username => "username", :password => "password") it gives me error saying

```
SOAP::FaultError: Username doesn't exist 
    from
```

I am sorry for making it too long! I have been searching about it for a long time now. But was not able to find the specific answer. I hope someone will have answer to my question. I am thinking that it might be some authentication error.

Comment: This error was caused by authentication, the username and password I was entering was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following can help you trouble shoot whats going on. It will dump the generated and received XML to console.

```
myWebServiceInstance.wiredump_dev = STDERR
```